# minuses used in an exponent are shown as spaces

Tags: braces, wiki

While editing some formula in Wikipedia (LaTeX) , the minus signs are shown like blank spaces when used between the braces of an exponent.
here's the code:

```
\begin{alignat}{2} \varepsilon_0 & = \frac{1}{(4 \pi \times 10^{-7} \, \textrm{N/A}^{2}) (299792458 \, \textrm{m/s})^2} \\ & = \frac{625000}{22468879468420441 \pi} \, \textrm{ F/m} \\ & \approx 8.85418781762039 \times 10^{-12} \, \textrm{F}{\cdot}\textrm{m}^{-1} \\ \end{alignat}
```

[image: here's how it looks:]

I'm using hyphen (not dash) and I'm using the minus sign from the Wikipedia signs. Also when I add something like a (!) sign or parentheses to the third or second exponent, it just makes all the minuses appear!
Even when I add (\\) to the start of the code the minuses appear.
Why does this happen?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If your question is about a problem when typing TeX notation on Wikipedia, then it is really about *MathML*, not *TeX*. In other words, this seems to be the wrong site for your question. Maybe [phabricator](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org) is a better place. There you find issues similar to yours, like [https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T269222](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T269222)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. The negative signs are typeset correctly for me. Can you post a complete document that includes your example and that produces the error? If you are actually doing this on Wikipedia, then @gernot is correct.

Comment: Oh! sorry .And thanks! I'll check!